# Intel Edison is detected but not recognized by Intel software

Tags: intel-edison

I have no actual clue on how to describe it clearly. Here's [how it happens](https://youtu.be/0rnhoNdWJno)

I tried install it manually but

```powershell
.\drvinstall.exe i .\intc_usbcomp.inf
INFO: Input file "C:\Users\skyca\Downloads\inteledisondriversetup1.2.1\intc_usbcomp.inf"
TEST: preinstalling driver package.
DriverPackagePreinstall Failed with error code 0xE0000247
```

And **.inf* file Installation is not working, an error will occurs during the process.

Comment: Have you tried to change the USB cable? The cheap USB cables may be the cause of behaviours like this.